# dotenv Error: Cannot find module at {Path}/main.jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, dotenv

I'm building a web-site, and using Firebase to store data. So, the private keys are on a .env file. I'm trying to import them in a firebase config file. I'm using import in order to use modules. And by following the guide in the dotenv doc, I ran 'node -r dotenv/config main.jsx' on my terminal. But I got an error, and I don't understand what to do.
Thanks !

> Folders' Architecture
> [image]

> Firebase.js
> [image]

> main.jsx
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using Vite which already supports .env files.

It's exposed in the `import.meta.env` object. Try replacing `process.env.` for `import.meta.env.` in your code.

See the documentation here: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files

Comment: Thank you ! It's really helps me =)